# How to monitor SQL statements that are doing hard delete

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-profiler

I have an application that interacts with SQL Server 2008. I want to write a tool that help me identifying the SQL statements that causes hard delete in the table. Is it possible to find out using the SQL Profiler? or should i write triggers in all the stored procedures to find out that? how to achieve it. any directions would be helpful.

Comment: what is exactly hard delete ? Do you have some sort of IsDeleted flag in the table ?

Comment: Yes we have flag that will do soft delete but at times we completely remove the row from the table that is what we need to identify

Answer (score 1):

First, take a look to [Monitoring the progress of an SQL query in SQL SERVER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3289670/monitoring-the-progress-of-an-sql-query-in-sql-server). To monitor progress for some sql query see [example](http://myqol.com/CodeSamples/CSharpConsole/CSharpConsoleExample.aspx?id=141).