# SQL Server - report query progress with sys.dm_exec_requests

Tags: sql-server, progress, dynamic-management-views

Is there a way to report a percentage progress of an own query using a `sys.dm_exec_requests` field: `percent_complete`? [msdn link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177648.aspx)

It works quite well for a BACKUP/RESTORE/SHRINK operations, for example:

`SELECT percent_complete FROM sys.dm_exec_requests WHERE command = 'DbccFilesCompact'`

`25.677`

but can it be used with user queries?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Monitoring the progress of an SQL query in SQL SERVER](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3289670/monitoring-the-progress-of-an-sql-query-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 1):

You MAY be able to get a VERY ROUGH approximation comparing the
query plans estimated count vs the actual rows in sys.dm_exec_query_profiles.

This will be a very bad indicator if the statistics are not current or if the selected query plan is 'sub-optimal'.

And as noted, this DMV may not be available to you, as it is 2014+ specific.

Comment: You should clarify this is 2014+