# Progressbar in SQL

Tags: javascript, sql, progress

So I learned that it's not exactly an easy task to create a progress bar for SQL queries. So I've tried to come up with an alternative solution to indicate when a task will be done. I figured I could time how long it would take to execute one query in the database and then use that information to create an estimation depending on how many queries that has to be performed and then create a progress bar from that information. I know it will not be a 100% reliable solution, because if something went wrong it would still show the progress bar, but it would at least give the user some indication when the job will be done, rather than just having a loading spinner.

Is there a better solution to this problem?

*edit to answer some questions*

It's the update function that takes time. I have maybe 15.000 inputs in the database and I have to update all 15.000 through an API. So first I have to pull out the id of all those and use them with an API to get the updated information, and then I have to execute all the 15.000 queries with the updated information. All this takes time. I doubt it can be done quickly. With a database of 15.000 queries it took me about 2 hours. I don't believe a spinner for 2 hours without an indication of when it will be done is realiable. I need some sort of estimation.

Note that updating the database is something that will be done very rarely. Like maybe once a week the user will update the database.

Comment: I suppose you already saw this one http://stackoverflow.com/a/617271/2042240

Comment: You said it yourself - it's not a reliable solution. Is it not better to let the user know a task is being executed and simply indicate that it's ongoing? A progressbar will just confuse users plus it's a metric ton of work for you to get it working. You can never even estimate how long a query might take. I'd just create a visual notifier that something's been done, without locking the entire UI.

Comment: Is there a better solution? Well, if I find myself thinking about a progress bar for SQL queries, I would start with optimizing my queries. Obviously they are much too slow at the moment. Use `EXPLAIN …` to find out where the bottlenecks are.

Comment: feeela and Mjh. I've updated the question with answers to your questions

Comment: 15 000 queries isn't much, it can be improved, probably both from the aspect of pulling and updating the data (however, there's no info on that part so we can't advise). You cannot estimate how long it will take - it's simply not possible and it will always be inaccurate - people will bug you about it. You can split the task in chunks. If you have 15 000 records, process them in chunks of 150. Each 150 processed = 1%. Every time you process 150, send back the info about the update and advance the progress bar.

Comment: Thanks that's actually a pretty good idea. I think what slows this down is not the actual SQL updating. It's because you have to pull the data through a link with every single input. But I really like your 150 chunk idea. Of course it's not always 15.000 entries. It can be any amount depending on a lot of factors. But i'll code my way around that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use reverse-ajax and then return a result into an iframe.

On the server-side, use repsonse.flush (ASP.NET) to get a partial result to the client when one iteration step is completed.

Output JavaScript code like:

```
window.parent.fnReportProgress(25.3)
```

Also, make sure you don't update on every progress message. 
Instead store the messages in an array, and then poll the array every x milliseconds (setInterval)  until complete. If you don't put all messages into an array, but instead update the progress bar immediately, you will get a bluescreen in IE, and only in IE. Chrome + FF work perfectly fine.

If you only need to support halfway modern browsers (IE10+) on halfway modern servers (IIS 8+), you can also use WebSockets.

WebSockets will also work on servers < IIS8, but then you'll have to develop the web-sockets server app separately, on a separate port.